# Process pairs of elements in a vector

Tags: arrays, r, iteration, binary-operators

Is there any standard function that can be applied to a single vector to process two elements per step?

For example, we have the vector:

```
> a <- c(8, 4, 5, 5, 7, 10)
```

and we want to subtract two neighbors elements:

```
> func(a, function (x1, x2) { x1-x2 })

[1] 4 -1 0 -2 -3
```

Comment: Try `-diff(a)` but something tells me you want something more general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general if you want to process consecutive vector elements in pairs you can get the first element in each pair with:

```
(first <- head(a, -1))
# [1] 8 4 5 5 7
```

And you can get the second element in each pair with

```
(second <- tail(a, -1))
# [1]  4  5  5  7 10
```

Then you can perform any operation you want on the consecutive elements. For instance, here's your operation:

```
first-second
# [1]  4 -1  0 -2 -3
```

Here's the product of consecutive elements:

```
first*second
# [1] 32 20 25 35 70
```

Note that your operation is actually pretty common so there is a specialized function to take the differences of consecutive elements, `diff`.

Comment: @TarasShchybovyk You should be able to compute `first` and `second` quickly, even for large vectors. Therefore the efficiency will come down to what you do with them. Fast vectorized operations like `-` and `*` will be fast, but slow operations (like ones involving loops) will be slow. Note that `-diff(a)` should be faster than `head(a, -1) - tail(a, -1)`.